# Remove a string from another string in javascript

Tags: javascript, string, split

I am trying to remove a String from another String.

```
var text = "This is a string";
```

I want to remove the word "is" so I will have

```
text = "This a string";
```

How do I go about that?

Comment: _"How do I go about that?"_ - you would start by doing some basic research; even just typing your question title verbatim into google would yield results that show you already.

Comment: @CBroe I had tried so many things before posting the question here. I didn't get the perfect solution which is why I posted the question

Comment: In such cases you need to show us what you tried, and what results you got.

Comment: @CBroe noted. I would put that into consideration next time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with `split()` and `filter()` function

```js
var text = "This is a string";
var res = text.split(" ").filter(a=> a != 'is').join(" ")
console.log(res)
```

**or** Regex `/\s+is/g`

[**Demo and Explanation**](https://regex101.com/r/SbHvWd/1/)

```js
var text = "This is a string";
var res = text.replace(/\s+is/g ,'')
console.log(res)
```

Comment: Result is not what OP asked for.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen then what  ? its same as a `text = "This  a string";`

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen Instead of downvoting everybody, offer a solution of you own

Comment: No: OP asked for "This  a string". Notice the 2 (TWO) spaces between `This` and `a`.

Comment: @natanel97: No I won't since the question should be closed.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen you'll downvote, i'll upvote :-)

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen op not mentioning `space`  .He was just remove the `string` from `is` that why it have a spaces .Better to ask the  about `space`  to Op

Comment: @prasad: If you look at the question You'll clearly see that the expected result should only remove the word `is` and leave everything else in there. That means that the expected result will contain two spaces between `This` and `a`...

Comment: @OlakunleMusiliuDosunmu you need a 2 spaces between `This__ a` in you output. Or normal string like  `This a`.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen see the Op comment in my answer. he was commented working perfect

Comment: I can see that but that indicates that OP didn't correctly describe his question, hence this question should, as I earlier stated, be closed.

Comment: @prasad a normal string. which is why I love your regex. Thank you very much.

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen .yes..you are right. its depend upon the quality of the question not with my answer.Op also need a normal string not with space

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen I guess it was my fault. I should have removed the space on the question. Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @OlakunleMusiliuDosunmu: If you want a "normal" string, single spaced, i.e. not two spaces between `This` and `a`, then `text = text.replace(' is ', ' ');` should suffice. No need for split, filter, join or regexp.

Answer (score 0):

Short way would be

```
var text = "This is a string";
var replace = "is";
var text = text.replace(new RegExp('\\b' + replace + '\\b'), "")
```

This would replace whole words and not parts of it. If you want to replace all the occurrences, you can use

```
var text = text.split(replace).join("");
```

Comment: Have you even tried this code and checked the result?

Comment: @SaniSinghHuttunen now i did and changed the code. I overlooked the whole word thing.

Comment: Now it works as expected.